# Basic tomcat website : threads or processes?

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, multiprocessing

This may be a very basic and simple question for experienced people, but I am a little confused about this :

If there are multiple connections to a website hosted on tomcat, will there be multiple threads or processes or what is the basic mechanism through which the underlying java, jsp code is accessed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomcat uses threads. There's an [article on java.net](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/06/06/distribute-detach-parallelize-tomcat.html?page=2#parallelize) that among other things goes through the most important configuration values:

> **maxThreads**: Tomcat uses a thread pool, and each request will be served
> by any idle thread in the thread pool. maxThreads decides the maximum
> number of threads that Tomcat can create to service requests.
>
> **minSpareThreads**: When Tomcat is initially started, it may not create
> maxThreads number of threads configured. Instead, it will create
> minSpareThreads and later, on an as-needed basis, it will create more
> threads until the number of threads reaches a maximum of maxThreads.
>
> **maxSpareThreads**: During off-load times, Tomcat doesn't require many of
> the threads in the pool. maxSpareThreads is the maximum number of idle
> threads Tomcat will retain in the pool. If this number is exceeded,
> excess threads are de-referenced to allow garbage collection.

I'd recommend checking out the article.

Answer (score 2):

The servlet container (Tomcat) maintains a thread pool which it uses to serve the requests. Tomcat never forks new processes.